# ReactiveUI exception handle recovery for ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask

Tags: reactiveui

Looking at many examples for `ReactiveUI` `ReactiveCommands`, the code looks something like

```
Delete = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable(x => DeleteImpl());
Delete.IsExecuting.ToProperty(this, x => x.IsDeleting, out _isDeleting);
Delete.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(ex => this.Log().ErrorException("Something went wrong", ex));
```

I am attempting to use `CreateAsyncTask` instead of `CreateAsyncObservable`

```
Delete = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(x => DeleteImpl());
Delete.IsExecuting.ToProperty(this, x => x.IsDeleting, out _isDeleting);
Delete.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(ex => this.Log().ErrorException("Something went wrong", ex));
```

The `Delete command` is bound to a WPF button.

With the `CreateAsyncObservable`, the button is enabled after recovery from the Error.

With the `CreateAsyncTask`, the button is disabled.

Beyond using `CreateAsyncObservable` (the logic is already written as async methods), how would I re-enable the button after the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the called method signature that I was using was causing the issue.

```
    private Task<Unit> DeleteImpl()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

was missing the `async` keyword

changing the method to

```
    private async Task<Unit> DeleteImpl()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```